# VariableSizedWrapGrid on Windows phone 8

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I'm trying to make a photo gallery with different item size on Windows Phone 8, like the VariableSizedWrapGrid on Windows 8. Do you have any idea what can I use to do this?

I tried with toolkit:WrapPanel with different item size but it's not really what I'm looking for..
Like this :

```
       <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <toolkit:WrapPanel/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a variable sized wrap grid control available in the Kinnara wp toolkit... maybe it can help? You can get it at [github here...](https://github.com/Kinnara/WPToolkit)